# Python3: for-loop break and else (if statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

## Background information:

hey,
I want to do the following: I have a dictionary with IDs as keys and lists with various things as value. One of the items of the value is a **string**. I want to check, if a list contains this **string**. And I want to do it for all keys in my dictionary.

- If the list contains the string, I want to print "String is valid"
- If the list does not contain the string, I want to print "String is NOT valid"

So far, so good.

Furthermore, the lists I want to check depend on one console input of the user, which specifies, which list should be checked. The console input is **"number"**.

My idea was to iterate over my dictionary and my list with a nested for-loop and compare, if the string(the item of the value) is equal to any list item. If it is, I want to break out of the loop. If the String is not found in the list, I want to execute the else-statement to print my "String is not valid" message.

## Code snippet:

```
def validationHelper(myDict, myList):
        for key in myDict:
            for value in myDict[key][0]:
                for item in myList:
                    if value==item:
                        validationHelper.true="String is valid"
                        break
                else:
                    validationHelper.true="Warning: String is NOT valid"
          
def validation(anyList,helperfunc):
    if anyList=="one":
        return helperfunc(finalDict,myList1)
    if anyList=="two":
         return helperfunc(finalDict,myList2)
    if anyList=="three":
         return helperfunc(finalDict,myList3)

validation(number, validationHelper)

print(validationHelper.true)
```

## Problem:

I am running this, but no matter if the string is in the list or not, I always get my printout for the else-statement. So, I guess I have an error in reasoning in my for-loop? Or maybe, I did not understand for-loops at all?! I have tried out different indentions with the else-statement, but couldnt solve my problem.

Comment: Remember you have three nested loops here; the `break` will only break out of the innermost one.

Comment: oh man, @DanielRoseman, I could have known that on my own -.-" . So, let me put my "thinking" into words now: I find the string in the list, and break the inner loop. I am back in the loop, "for value in my Dict[key][0]" and perform my searching for the next key etc. My print will be THE LAST thing, which is written to validationHelper.true, right? In order to fully terminate all loops upon finding a match, I would add break statements, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to change your function the following way (without changing the logic):

```
def validationHelper(myDict, myList):
    for key in myDict:
        for value in myDict[key][0]:
            for item in myList:
                if value==item:
                    return "String is valid" # Add here to exit
    return "Warning: String is NOT valid" # will be returned inf nothing will be found in your 3 loops

def validation(anyList,helperfunc):
    if anyList=="one":
        return helperfunc(finalDict,myList1)
    if anyList=="two":
         return helperfunc(finalDict,myList2)
    if anyList=="three":
         return helperfunc(finalDict,myList3)

validation(number, validationHelper)

print(validationHelper)
```

This will help you to exit your 3 nested loops as it was mentioned in comments.
Because in the negative case on first wrong occurrence you don't need to check anything else.

Comment: Shouldn't the return be replacing the break, rather than in the else case?

Comment: so, return means "end all loops", basically, and works like that? Because, if I adjust my code this way and try to print(validationHelper.true), I get the following error:     print(validationHelper.true)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'true'

Comment: @Arseniy in the case of a negative occurrence for the first key in my dictionary, I want to go on with the second key. So I need to continue checking, just that I have a new string then, to check against the same list

Comment: @Shushiro I got it sorry for misreading your question, check my updated answer. And return means - "stop executing of this function" and return something. oh and you need return string and not `.true`

Comment: @Arseniy ah ok, somehow the updated answer showed up just now

Comment: Is the innermost loop needed? I would think the `in` keyword would make it more readable and idiomatic.

Comment: @HalfTau Yes, but the point of my answer is not to review the code (we have special site for it). I just want to point on basic problems in question.

Comment: This won't print the validation message. It either needs to print `validation(number, validationHelper)` (probably a better option), or store the message in `validationHelper.true` before returning.

Answer (score 1):

Use return to break all of your loop. Having an else statement is not necessary if you don't have any if statement to begin with.

```
def validationHelper(myDict, myList):
    for item in myList:
        if item in myDict.values():
            return ("String is valid")
    return ("String is NOT valid")

def validation(anyList,helperfunc):
    if anyList=="one":
        return helperfunc(finalDict,myList1)
    elif anyList=="two":
        return helperfunc(finalDict,myList2)
    elif anyList=="three":
        return helperfunc(finalDict,myList3)

validation(number, validationHelper)

print(validationHelper.true)
```

Using elif instead of multiple if is a better practice. Be careful with indentions next time.

Also you might want to check .keys() and .values()

You can replace:

```
for key in myDict:
    for value in myDict[key][0]:
```

with:

```
for value in myDict.values():
```

Comment: yet, my "else" was meant to be a for-loop else clause, not an else of if/else: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Comment: You don't need an else statement then. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give a good explanation of how to break out of multiple loops. But you could also simplify your code by using Python's built-in functions and list comprehensions, like this:

```
def validationHelper(myDict, myList):
    if any(v in myList for val in myDict.values() for v in val[0]):
        validationHelper.true="String is valid"
    else:
        validationHelper.true="Warning: String is NOT valid"

def validation(anyList,helperfunc):
    if anyList=="one":
        return helperfunc(finalDict,myList1)
    if anyList=="two":
         return helperfunc(finalDict,myList2)
    if anyList=="three":
         return helperfunc(finalDict,myList3)

validation(number, validationHelper)

print(validationHelper.true)
```

This should be as efficient as your code, since `any` short circuits at the first match. And it may be a little more readable. (Note that multi-level list comprehensions go in the same order as regular `for` loops.)